# How to initialize static const char array for ASCII codes [C++]

Tags: c++, casting

I want to initialize a  static const char array with ASCII codes in a constructor, here's my code:

```
class Card
{ 
public:
    Suit(void)
    {    
        static const char *Suit[4] = {0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06}; // here's the problem
        static const string *Rank[ 13 ] = {'A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K'}; // and here.
}
```

However i got a whole lot of errors stating that

- 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'char' to 'const std::string *'
- 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'const std::string *'

please help me! Thank you so much.

Comment: converting from `char` to `const std::string*` is the least of your worries

Comment: `Suit(void)` is not a constructor. You declare a constructor by declaring a function with no return type and **the same name as the class**.

Comment: Also, strings should not be used as a universal variable type. Enumerations are recommended here.

Answer (score 4):

You are initializing just one array of characters, so you want:

```
static const char Suit[] = {0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06};
static const char Rank[] = {'A', '2', ...};
```

The forms that you are using are declaring arrays of strings and then initializing them with single strings.  If you do want `Rank` to be an array of strings, the initializers need to be in double quotes:

```
static const char* Rank[] = {"A", "2", ...};
```

or:

```
static const std::string Rank[] = {"A", "2", ...};
```

Answer (score 0):

An array of chars has type `const char[]`. What you have, `const char*[]` is an array of pointers.